# SharePoint Online REST Api datetime query

Tags: javascript, rest, api, datetime, sharepoint-online

I have a list of events. I want to get all future events and all events were the start date has past but the end date is still in the future. Here is a picture to describe what I want.

[image]

My incomplete code so far:

```
function ReFormatTime() {
        return moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00");
    }

 var now = ReFormatTime();
        var _url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items?$select=EndDate%2CID%2CEventDate%2CLinkTitle%2CIsBlock%2CProgram_x0020_Id&$filter=EventDate ge datetime'" + now + "'&$top=5000";
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you want all events with end dates today and in the future. The $filter only needs to test the end date.

Solved it like this:

```
  var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00");
  var _url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items?$select=EndDate%2CID%2CEventDate%2CLinkTitle%2CIsBlock%2CProgram_x0020_Id&$filter=EndDate ge datetime'" + now + "'&$top=5000";
```